# Pass command line arguments from bash script to program verbatim, with escaping

Tags: bash, unix, sh

So, I have a bash script that needs to run X if `--xyz` flag is set, and Y otherwise. It also needs to pass all command line arguments through to the programs it runs. My problem with this is that I can't get it to pass the arguments exactly as they appear, instead it either escapes things that don't need escaped, or strips the escaping from things that should be escaped.

This is my test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$@"
args=$@
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
while test $# -gt 0
do
    case "$1" in
        --xyz) echo ${args/--xyz/}
            exit $?
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "$args"
printf %s "$args"
echo
echo "$(printf %s "$args")"
echo "$(printf %q "$args")"
```

I then test this like so:

```
[jearls@earlzpremb X]$ ./test.sh -c Foo\ Bar
-c Foo Bar
-c Foo Bar
-c Foo Bar
-c Foo Bar
-c\ Foo\ Bar
[jearls@earlzpremb X]$ echo -c Foo\ Bar
-c Foo Bar
[jearls@earlzpremb X]$ echo "-c Foo\ Bar"
-c Foo\ Bar
```

I need it to be like the last command. Foo\ Bar retaining the escaping for the space, but no escaping for the space after -c.

I don't have any control over what arguments are passed into this script, so I can't do double escaping or anything like that.

How exactly can I reach my goal of passing command line arguments basically verbatim with escaping intact to another program?

Comment: You basically cannot in `sh` but if a Bash solution is acceptable, you just basically need to collect the arguments in an array. I'm sure there are multiple duplicates of this question on SO.

Comment: Bash is acceptable, though I'd of course like to keep with just sh if possibe

Comment: You need to remove the `--xyz` argument before calling the other program?

Comment: In addition to the array solution `array=( "$@" )`, you can look into substring extraction: e.g. passing `${@//--xyz/}` to the programs to eliminate `--xyz` from the arg list.

Comment: I'd make an alias in .bashrc to execute the bash script when the command to execute the program is run, and then just write the bash script so that the program itself will be executed by the bash script. That's the easiest way, although it's not exactly pretty.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good thought and might work here but won't work if that's valid in any other argument value.

Comment: `args=$@` -- storing an array in a scalar -- is inherently broken. Will never ever work right. Don't do it. `args=( "$@" )` -- storing an array in an array -- is safe.

Comment: `printf '%q ' "${args[@]}"` will then build an eval'able, quoted string from that array... but... why?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yea, I'm very inexperienced with using bash to make actual scripts.. or anything beyond basic usage as a shell really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (easily) convert an argument *list* to a string in a way that it can be converted back to a list. Fortunately, you rarely actually need to do that.

It's not clear to me exactly what your requirements are, but here's a simple script which seems to demonstrate the behaviour you expect:

```
# Function to execute if --xyz in argument list
X() { local -i i=0
      for arg in "$@"; do echo X$((++i)): "$arg"; done
}
# Function to call otherwise
Y() { local -i i=0
      for arg in "$@"; do echo Y$((++i)): "$arg"; done
}

# Select one or the other
x_or_y() {
  local arg
  # Scan arguments for --xyz (Not very precise)
  for arg in "$@"; do
    case "$arg" in
      --xyz) X "$@";
             return $?;;
      --)    break;;
    esac
  done
  # No --xyz found
  Y "$@"
}

# Demonstrate that arguments are passed verbatim:
$ x_or_y something "a b c" 'a backslash\inside'
Y1: something
Y2: a b c
Y3: a backslash\inside

$ x_or_y something --xyz "a b c" 'a backslash\inside'
X1: something
X2: --xyz
X3: a b c
X4: a backslash\inside
```

With bash, if you need to remove the `--xyz` argument, you can use an array. (You could also use `set --`, but I think the array is clearer):

```
x_or_y() {
  local -i i=1
  local arg
  local todo=Y
  local args=()
  # Scan arguments for --xyz (Not very precise)
  for arg in "$@"; do
    ((++i))
    case "$arg" in
      --xyz) todo=X; break;;
      --)    args+=("$arg"); break;;
      *)     args+=("$arg");;
    esac
  done
  # Call with the args scanned and the rest of the args:
  "$todo" "${args[@]}" "${@:i}"
}
```

**Edit:** As Etan Reisner notes, it is possible to do this without an array. The array is a useful technique, but for this problem you can do it with substring expressions:

```
x_or_y() {
  local -i i
  local -i skip=0
  local todo=Y
  # Scan arguments for --xyz (Not very precise)
  for ((i=1; i<=$#; ++i)); do
    case "${!i}" in
      --xyz) todo=X; skip=1; break;;
      --)    break;;
    esac
  done
  # Call with the args scanned and the rest of the args:
  "$todo" "${@:1:i-1}" "${@:i+skip}"
}
```

Comment: That ends up calling it multiple times with one argument at a time.. That won't work for me. I need it called once with all arguments. (echo was just for example sake)

Comment: This should just call it once unless you missed the `return` line or something.

Comment: @Earlz: The `X` and `Y` functions refer to what you want to do; they're not part of the solution. I just included them to show that it works.

Comment: Why the `return $?`? Isn't `$?` the default value used by `return`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Indeed, $? is redundant there.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the `--xyz` argument from the argument list the following should work (though I don't know if this is usable with `/bin/sh`).

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

c() {
    printf 'argc: %s\n' "$#";
    printf 'argv: %s\n' "$@"
}

counter=1
for arg; do
    case $arg in
        --xyz)
            echo "Found $arg at position $counter"
            break
        ;;
    esac
    ((counter++))
done

echo "${@::$counter}" "${@:$((counter + 1))}"
c "${@::$counter}" "${@:$((counter + 1))}"
$ ./test -c Foo\ Bar -a Blah\ Quux
-c Foo Bar -a Blah Quux
argc: 4
argv: -c
argv: Foo Bar
argv: -a
argv: Blah Quux
$ ./test.sh -c Foo\ Bar --xyz -a Blah\ Quux
Found --xyz at position 3
-c Foo Bar -a Blah Quux
argc: 4
argv: -c
argv: Foo Bar
argv: -a
argv: Blah Quux
```

Comment: Nice. Adapted in my solution, hope that's ok.